# Python model Foreignkey backward relation

Tags: python, django

I need to save all the Countries of a continent through attribute "countries" of the Continent model. How can I do this? 
Thanks.

```
from django.db import models

class Continent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique = True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique = True)
    allCountries = models.Manager()
    countries = ???

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255 )
    capital = models.CharField(max_length=255 )
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique = True)
    population = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    area = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
```

Comment: Firstly, you are more likely to get answers if you tag your question properly: I have added `django`. Secondly, this is trivially answered in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) as well as fully explained in the tutorial - if you don't already know how to do this, you should go back and do [part 1 of the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api) again.

Answer (score 2):

To get all countries from a given continent you have to do the following:

```
continent = Continent.objects.get(name='Europe')
countries = continent.country_set.all() # returns all countries from Europe
```

You don't need to add a countries field in Continent

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This code works, but I needed to achieve the result by modifying the model.